# How to change color of Bootstrap disabled button?

Tags: html, css, button

I am using a bootstrap button on a page of my website and I want to change the color of a disabled button. A button that is "grayed out" and you cannot click. Is there a way I can change the color of this using CSS? Any class for this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In case your button look like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Button</button>
```

the next CSS code will change its color (when disabled only):

```
.btn.btn-primary[disabled] {
    background-color: #00ff00;
}
```

or

```
.btn.btn-primary:disabled{
    background-color: #00ff00;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly; you need to use `:disabled`.
Here is a working code:

```css
#work {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  color: black;
}

#work:disabled{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button id="work"disabled="true" type="submit">Button </button>
```

Comment: Alright so this is the normal button:
`.col-boosting .btn-pay-rank {
 height: 65px;
 font-weight: bold;
 background: #e06b38;
 border: none;
 box-shadow: 0 7px 0 0 #c7511f;
}`

I tried this:
`.col-boosting .btn-pay-rank:disabled {
 height: 65px;
 background: #dd5a22;
 border: none;
 box-shadow: 0 7px 0 0 #dd5a22;
}`

But it seems to still not work

Comment: Looks like you found your answer, let me know if you still need help.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do this because I was disabling the button in javascript.

```
 var button = document.querySelector("#button");
            button.disabled = 'disabled';
            button.setAttribute("style", "background-color: #799b48");
```

Comment: Hmmn I think you don't *have* to do the style-part that way. If you set the disabled attribute dynamically to 'disabled' via javascript, the css-':disabled'-styling would still apply. And it would also work for buttons that are disabled to begin with..